# Number with comma in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qstring

I try to fetch a float number from a `QString` using `toFloat()` method but i get `0` for every number i fetch. I think number format is wrong and system does not recognize it, how can i set right format for these kind of numbers : `119,68648` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#toDouble

Here is the example code from the documentation:

```
bool ok;
double d;

QLocale german(QLocale::German);
d = german.toDouble( "1234,56", &ok );  // ok == true, d == 1234.56
d = german.toDouble( "1.234,56", &ok ); // ok == true, d == 1234.56
d = german.toDouble( "1234.56", &ok );  // ok == false

d = german.toDouble( "1.234", &ok );    // ok == true, d == 1234.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a locale where the decimal separator is a comma for your application.

Or you can replace commas by dots before doing the conversion to be able to accept both number formats.

```
float value = yourString.replace(",", ".").toFloat();
```

Comment: can you provide an example or link ?